# iOS - Create a video from array of images and save to camera roll

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video, avfoundation

I am trying to create a flipbook type video out of an array of images using Objective C. I'm currently using AVCaptureDevice to capture a few picture frames per second of output, and am trying to figure out how to convert these images to be a video. I've seen some examples that use AVAssetWriter, but how do I convert to a video that can be then saved to the camera roll?

Comment: You can in fact convert the images to a savable video using AVAssetWriter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: How to make a movie with a series of images using AVAssetWriter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831967/ios-how-to-make-a-movie-with-a-series-of-images-using-avassetwriter)